# Google Android Development Tool crashes periodically on Linux host...is this normal?

Tags: android, linux, crash, adt, opensuse

I'm running the Google Android Development Tool (Build: v22.3.0-887826) on a 64-bit openSuse 13.1 Linux on a laptop with 4gb RAM and a 2.4ghz processor. The Android Development Tool installed with no problems automatically and also updates fine from Google servers. It runs great except that it crashes every 20 minutes or so. The crashes do not coincide with when I am building an application, or running the device emulator. Typically I'll be editing text in a file when the entire tool set goes away...doesn't lock up, the development tool window crashes and I'm left looking at the desktop. 
Has anyone else experienced this? Thanks in advance for helpful, on-topic responses.

Comment: Crashing that often isn't common, although eclipse is known to be buggy.  Are you editing a large application?  I have found that when doing so I have to increase the amount of memory the JDK is allowed to use for Eclipse itself.  That was on Windows, but I believe it was a global issue.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. No, I'm working on the beginners tutorial.

Comment: Okay, FWIW I can replicate the crash now. It does it when I'm adding java code in the src directory. The crash occurs about 1/2 second after the code completion pop-up appears.

Comment: Got it...running eclipse as ./eclipse -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla seems to have corrected this reported bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, this bug has been reported to ADT developers as well as previously documented here on stackoverflow. Current workaround is to start eclipse from the command line with,

./eclipse -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Comment: I just upgraded to the v23 Android Development Tool (adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702). I am still having the periodic crashes described last February in v22, and adding **-vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla** to the eclipse command stops them.